# C# / WPF / Prism : Suggestion on how to create dynamic prism regions containing other dynamic regions

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, region

I have a Prism 7 application that i want to dynamically add some containers to.

I want to have different kinds of containers (i.e from different classes and in the example denoted A, B and C) and there could be 0..N containers of the same type.

Each container can have 0..N number sub devices attached to it, also these dynamically created.

I'm unable to figure out how to accomplish this since the regions on the dynamically created containers interfere with one another.

An example of what I'm trying achieve is found here.
https://github.com/metscore/DynamicPrism7Regions

Any tip on how this is achieved is greatly appreciated !

King regards
Magnus

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming here later (or myself after I forgot all about it) I've updated the example where I have it resonable working.

[Visual result of the testprogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ddie.png)

The idea is to have a dynamic region name that is "unique" and in my case is the property of the view model.
Currently there is no way to remove regions, but coming this far I hope that this part is going to be the easy one.